# XSL template for an 'array' of data inside a template on the first node

Tags: xml, xslt

This is a continuation of my Stackoverflow post
[Matching templates with different configuration on the same node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970677/matching-templates-with-different-configuration-on-the-same-node), as was suggested in my original post [Nesting xsl templates and referring multiple templates to the same node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966059/nesting-xsl-templates-and-referring-multiple-templates-to-the-same-node)

How do I implement a template on the first ROW tag, which may well be the only ROW tag in the source XML?
My question concerns the last nodes in the ROW tag, containing E1EDL44 in the tagname in the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
    <ROW>
        <EDI_DC40.TABNAM><DATA>EDI_DC40</DATA></EDI_DC40.TABNAM>
        <E1EDL20.VBELN><DATA>649758</DATA></E1EDL20.VBELN>
        <E1EDL18.QUALF><DATA>ORI</DATA></E1EDL18.QUALF>
        <E1EDL24.POSNR>000001</E1EDL24.POSNR>
        <E1EDL41.QUALI>001</E1EDL41.QUALI>
        <E1EDL37.EXIDV><DATA>5650327422</DATA></E1EDL37.EXIDV>
        <!-- These E1EDL44 lines will appear the same on every ROW, in case there is more than one ROW-->
        <!-- There are more tags, actually, left out for simplicity-->
        <E1EDL44.VELIN>
             <DATA>1</DATA>
             <DATA>2</DATA>
             <DATA>3</DATA>
        </E1EDL44.VELIN>
        <E1EDL44.POSNR>
             <DATA>000001</DATA>
             <DATA>000123</DATA>
             <DATA>456789</DATA>
        </E1EDL44.POSNR>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <EDI_DC40.TABNAM><DATA>EDI_DC40</DATA></EDI_DC40.TABNAM>
        <E1EDL20.VBELN><DATA>649758</DATA></E1EDL20.VBELN>
        <E1EDL18.QUALF><DATA>ORI</DATA></E1EDL18.QUALF>
        <E1EDL24.POSNR>2</E1EDL24.POSNR>
        <E1EDL41.QUALI>002</E1EDL41.QUALI>
        <E1EDL37.EXIDV><DATA>5650327422</DATA></E1EDL37.EXIDV>
        <E1EDL44.VELIN>
             <DATA>1</DATA>
             <DATA>2</DATA>
             <DATA>3</DATA>
        </E1EDL44.VELIN>
        <E1EDL44.POSNR>
             <DATA>000001</DATA>
             <DATA>000123</DATA>
             <DATA>456789</DATA>
        </E1EDL44.POSNR>
    </ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

The result must be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DELVRY05>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
      <VBELN>649758</VBELN>
      <E1EDL18 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>ORI</QUALF>
      </E1EDL18>
      <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
        <POSNR>000001</POSNR>
        <E1EDL41 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>001</QUALI>
        </E1EDL41>
      </E1EDL24>
      <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
        <POSNR>2</POSNR>
        <E1EDL41 SEGMENT="1">
          <QUALI>002</QUALI>
        </E1EDL41>
      </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
      <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
        <EXIDV>5650327422</EXIDV>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>1</VELIN>
          <POSNR>000001</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>2</VELIN>
          <POSNR>000123</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>3</VELIN>
          <POSNR>456789</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
      </E1EDL37>
  </IDOC>
</DELVRY05>
```

With the help of Sebastien (see previously mentioned post), my take on the xslt looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fm"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DELVRY05>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:FMPDSORESULT/fm:ROW[1]"/>
    </DELVRY05>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <TABNAM><xsl:value-of select="fm:EDI_DC40.TABNAM/fm:DATA"/></TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL20.VBELN/fm:DATA"/></VBELN>
        <E1EDL18 SEGMENT="1"><QUALF><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL18.QUALF/fm:DATA"/></QUALF></E1EDL18>
        
        <!-- Use template for elements that are present mutltiple times. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../fm:ROW/fm:E1EDL24.POSNR"/>
        <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
          <EXIDV><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL37.EXIDV/fm:DATA"/></EXIDV>
          <VHILM><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL37.VHILM/fm:DATA"/></VHILM>
          <EXIDV2><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL37.EXIDV2/fm:DATA"/></EXIDV2>
          <EXIDA><xsl:value-of select="fm:E1EDL37.EXIDA/fm:DATA"/></EXIDA>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:E1EDL44.VELIN/fm:DATA"/>
        </E1EDL37>
      </E1EDL20>
    </IDOC>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fm:E1EDL24.POSNR">
    <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
      <POSNR><xsl:value-of select="."/></POSNR>
      <E1EDL41 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALI><xsl:value-of select="../fm:E1EDL41.QUALI"/></QUALI>
      </E1EDL41>
    </E1EDL24>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fm:E1EDL44.VELIN/fm:DATA">
    <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
      <VELIN><xsl:value-of select="."/></VELIN>
      <POSNR><xsl:value-of select="../../fm:E1EDL44.POSNR/fm:DATA"/></POSNR>
    </E1EDL44>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which works good for VELIN, but not for POSNR, where it always shows the first DATA tag data:

```
      <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
        <EXIDV>5650327422</EXIDV>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>1</VELIN>
          <POSNR>000001</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>1</VELIN>
          <POSNR>000001</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
        <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
          <VELIN>3</VELIN>
          <POSNR>000001</POSNR>
        </E1EDL44>
      </E1EDL37>
```

How do I fix my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use `<POSNR><xsl:value-of select="../../fm:E1EDL44.POSNR/fm:DATA[position() = current()]"/></POSNR>`. This assumes the matched elements indeed contain the values `1,2,3,4,..`, as in your sample data.

Otherwise store

```
 <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
```

and use `<POSNR><xsl:value-of select="../../fm:E1EDL44.POSNR/fm:DATA[$pos]"/></POSNR>`

Comment: Fantastic that worked!
This:
select="../../fm:E1EDL44.POSNR/fm:DATA[position() = current()]"/></POSNR>
would depend on the value of VELIN (being ascending 1, 2, 3), which is not true in my case, wheras storing the variable inside the template worked perfect. Thank you very much!! My vote up isn't visible, because of lack of reputation, I just joined. Very much obliged :)